# Arrange numbers 2 to 20 to the hexagons (part 2)

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, visual

Arrange numbers $2$ to $20$ in the hexagons using the following rules:

1. The difference between two adjacent hexagons is greater than $4$.
2. Numbers inside the green hexagons are even numbers.
3. Numbers inside the yellow hexagons are prime numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are no unique solutions, but two.

> [image: Solution]
>  
>  3 and 5 can't be filled by logic.

*Sorry for the hand drawn numbers. I was too lazy to open my Photoshop.*

---

Below is how I named each cells.

[image: Cell names]

*Once again, sorry for the hand drawn letters.*

---

And the steps below are how I solved this. Basically I kept tracking what numbers can go into a cell, and eliminating those numbers.

> 1. Two white cells should be one of 9, 15.
>  2. C1 != 5 ~ 19, and 2 is gone. Therefore **C1 is 4**.
>  3. E1 != 2 ~ 8 + 11 ~ 13 (possible: 17, 19)
>  4. If D1 is 15, both 17 and 19 can't go into E1. Therefore **D1 is 9**, and **B1 is 15**.
>  5. **E2 is 14** by adjacent cells.
>  6. A1 != 11 ~ 20 (possible: 3, 5, 7)
>  7. B2 != {2 ~ 9, 16 ~ 20} (possible: 10, 12)
>  8. D2 != 8 ~ 20 (possible: 3, 5, 7)
>  9. C3 != 3 ~ 12 (possible: 16, 18)
>  10. E3 != {3 ~ 7, 14 ~ 20} (possible: 11, 13)
>  11. F2 != {3 ~ 7, 9 ~ 18}. Therefore **F2 is 19**, and **E1 is 17**.
>  12. G2 != {2 ~ 6, 10 ~ 20}. Therefore **G2 is 7**.
>  13. H1 != 2 ~ 11. Therefore **H1 is 13**, and **E3 is 11**.
>  14. I1 != 3 ~ 17. Therefore **I1 is 18**, and **C3 is 16**, and **B2 is 10**.
>  15. **G1 is 8**, and **G3 is 6**, and **H2 is 12**.

Comment: Superb and clear read. Just suggesting a notational improvement, instead of labeling the hexes {A_i, ..., H_i}, why not label the yellows {P_i} for primes, greens {E_i} for evens, and the white {O_i} for odd (composite) numbers? (of course the adjacent interconnections become slightly trickier)

Answer (score 4):

Eureka!! Eureka!!

> [image]

Challenge faced

> Cracking the cluster of prime numbers near 20 was bit tricky - Once that was fixed to 2 combinations - placement of 2 helped the choice

Comment: Oh, I was few seconds late while double-checking my solution.

Comment: @Otami, Yep.. but you gave a better explanation.. upvote for that :)